# how add ValidationMessageFor to view with list of models

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to add some validation to my MVC5 form. I have added required to the model and it is working for other pages but this page is different. In the view I used the CustomerModel, but as it may return more than 1 value my model at the top of the page is the list of CustomerModel. So when I wanted to have the line for validation I am not sure how should I write it. it is working for 1 value like this:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Account_Number);
```

But now my model is list and I tried like this too but it gave me error:

```
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model[1].Account_Number);
```

this is my complete view:

```
enter code here


    @model List<CSAProject.Models.CustomerModel>
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Search By Account Number";
  }

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table style="border: none">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: red">@*By RemoteRefNumber*@<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">Enter Account Number:
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
            @Html.TextBox("Account_Number")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model[1].Account_Number);
        </td>


        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: red">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  }


@if (Model.Count > 0)
  {
     <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Account Number
        </th>
        <th>First Name
        </th>
        <th>Last Name
        </th>
        <th>Last 4SSN
        </th>
        <th>Zip
        </th>
        <th>is Registered
        </th>
        <th>Online Agreement
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var customer in Model)
    {


        <tr>
            <td>
                @customer.Account_Number
            </td>

            <td>
                @customer.First_Name
            </td>

            <td>
                @customer.Last_Name
            </td>

            <td>
                @customer.Last4SSN
            </td>

            <td>
                @customer.Mailing_Zip
            </td>

            <td>
                @if (customer.isRegistered == true)
                {
                    <text>Yes</text> 
                }
                else
                {
                    <text>No</text> 
                }

            </td>

            <td>
                @if (customer.Online_Agreement == true)
                {
                    <text>Yes</text> 
                }
                else
                {
                    <text>No</text> 
                }
            </td>
            <td>@* Name of button, action name,name of controler,parameter of action,class*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "CustomerDetail", new { id = customer.Customer_ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
       }

  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

And this is my model:

```
 public class CustomerModel
     {

    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ACCOUNT NUMBER")]
    public string Account_Number { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("FIRST NAME")]
    public string First_Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("LAST NAME")]
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
   and the rest
      }
```

and this is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult SearchByAccountNumber(InputDataAccount model)
        {
               customerServiceUri =       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"].ToString();

           List<CustomerModel> customerModels = new List<CustomerModel>();

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
               if (model.Account_Number != null)
                    {
                     var uri = string.Format("{0}GetCustomerByAccountNumber",    customerServiceUri);

                    // Create an object to convert to JSON
                   var data = new
                    {
                       CustomerData = new
                        {
                           Account_Number = model.Account_Number

                       }
                   };

                   // Convert object to byte[]
                    var dataToSend =   Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

                 // Create request to the web service
                var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                //Meta data
                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
                req.Method = "POST";

                // Write the bytes to the web service (POST the data)
                req.GetRequestStream().Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);

                // THIS is where we call the web service with the posted data
                var response = req.GetResponse();

                // Create a string container for my JSON response
                string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        jsonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                // Convert the JSON from our response into our response object "SearchByNameResult"
                var jsonReult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchByAccountNumberResult>(jsonResponse);

                // The cutomers is the value of the result property
                var customers = jsonReult.GetCustomerByAccountNumberResult;

                // Create CustomerModels from our results
                foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    customerModels.Add(new CustomerModel
                    {
                        Customer_ID = Convert.ToInt32(customer.Customer_ID),
                        Account_Number = customer.Account_Number,
                        First_Name = customer.First_Name,
                        Last_Name = customer.Last_Name,
                        isRegistered = customer.isRegistered,
                        Online_Agreement = customer.Online_Agreement,
                        Last4SSN = customer.Last4SSN,
                        Mailing_Zip = customer.Mailing_Zip
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return View(customerModels);
    }
```

Comment: @Stephen Muecke yes It is a search form that I wanted to make sure customer enter the account number then hit search and it shows data under search button inside a table (in same view) But it may return 2 different record with same account number.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can you explain more about the 2 properties you talking about.I have added the model to my top code too.